# Starting OPEN CL - How to bring a GPU card to its maximum?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, opencl, gpu

I am new to GPU computing and need some advice and since as it seems that OPEN CL becomes the new industry standard I would like to move on with it, instead of CUDA.

So I am used to Python and multiprocessing which is a fantastic and simple tool. Now I want to expand my processing capacity with GPU power. So far I have just one function which needs to be calculated. So what I do so far is calling the function with some numbers to calculated and get the result back after 10 seconds.

How can I do this with OPEN CL and what is the best tool to program OPEN CL under Python ?

It is possible to simply use a decorator, send the function to the GPU card and this will be calculate in Light speed ? If possible I want to sent this function several thousand times to the GPU for parallel processing to get 100% calculation power ?

How can I do is and is OPEN CL the right tool of doing ?

Any advice or demo code is appreciated.

regards
Frank

Answer (score 1):

The most popular method of using OpenCL from Python is probably [PyOpenCL](http://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/). PyOpenCL is a full wrapper around the OpenCL API, so provides every piece of OpenCL functionality within Python, along with some really nice pythonic simplifications. It's not quite as easy as just adding a decorator to a function, but it's still pretty straightforward to get up and running with it. There's a good set of documentation in the above link with some examples, and there's also a set of examples in the [Hands-on OpenCL Tutorial](https://github.com/HandsOnOpenCL/Exercises-Solutions) from the University of Bristol.

There have been a couple of attempts to simplify the Python+OpenCL experience even further by providing a single-source approach similar to that which you are after. [Clyther](https://github.com/srossross/Clyther) is one such attempt, although it doesn't seem to be active at the moment and I don't believe it ever reached a 'release'. A more recent attempt is [Urutu](https://github.com/urutu/Urutu), which seems to be currently under development but shows promise (see also the [poster at GTC](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2014/poster/pdf/P4233_python_urutu_CUDA_OpenCL.pdf)). I haven't used either of these yet so cannot vouch for them personally.

To answer your final question: Yes, if you have a parallel workload and are looking for portable GPU acceleration, then OpenCL is the right tool for you.